# Bootstrap width issues

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am having an issue with the following site.

I can't figure out 2 things.

1) Why does the "Featured Photo / Video" and Twitter feed not show in the full width when you are viewing at sm/xs size?

2) Why do the 3 ads under the Twitter feed not show at all on sm/xs size?

As far as I can see they are both contained in a DIV with classes of col-sm-12 col-xs-12, so they should both show at full width there, correct?

```
<article>

<h2 class="entry-title" itemprop="headline">

Featured Video / Photo

</h2>


<iframe width="100%" height="300" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/5kIIsSi3aOQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>


</article>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Because you gave the parent an ID "primary-mid" and that overwrites the CSS

```
#primary-mid {
    width: 55%;
}
```

2) Same reason as Nr 1...

To avoid this, use media queries yourself, or don't overwrite the Bootstrap width with your own.